# Create an invoice from a sales order using XML-RPC (Python)

Tags: odoo

I'm following the external APIs documentation : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html

to implement our companies requirements. I'm required to create a sales order and automatically create an invoice after that. The sales order part is done but I cant seem to be able to attach the Invoice to the Sales order

I've tried linking it via the 'invoice_ids' field but the documentation does not mention how to provide a many2many field in it. here is the code:

```
many2manyInvoice =  [(4, invoice_id)]   

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))

#Admin user Id
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'write', [[sales_order_id],     {'invoice_ids':many2manyInvoice}])
```

The response returned is `200` , but nothing is happening on the sales order level. I think its the way that I defined the field that might be incorrect.

Can someone help with this issue ? Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be enough to link the invoice lines to the related sales order lines. Okay that is a many2many field too. You need to know which invoice line(s) (IDs) will be connected to which order line (ID). Just use the write method on sale.order.line and connect the invoice lines (field is `invoice_lines`) by using the triplets for example [(6, 0, invoice_ids)] to overwrite all connections or an example for single additions: [(4, invoice_id_1), (4, invoice_id_2) ...].

Comment: @CZoellner may I know what the num 6 and 0 from [(6, 0, invoice_ids)] stand for?

Comment: 6 i'v already written about and the 0 within is just a placeholder for "nothing", because this triplet command don't need a value on that (second) position.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is happening on the sales order level because you are not creating a sales record, writing to it without doing anything. Not sure if this would work in your specific case but here is what I would do.

Use the Pro-forma invoice https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/sales/invoicing/proforma.html

Then when a sales record is created run the "Send pro-forma invoice" method using the web api. This takes care of the db linking, as it can get very complicated.

Comment: How can we run a method from web api ? I'm new to Odoo so I'm not very familiar with this.

Comment: I don't know the ID specifically for your action. But Here is an example I used for running an action over the web API on Odoo 13. `models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'ir.cron', 'method_direct_trigger', 10)`  Note the number 10 is the ID for my action within odoo. Yours will probably be different.